# Does gcc compiler have any option to recognize memory corruption at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char arrDst[5] = {0};
  char arrSrc[10] = "123456";
  memcpy( arrDst, arrSrc, sizeof( arrSrc ) );
  return 0;
}
```

Here in this program it is clear that there is a memory corruption.

Is there any option in gcc compiler by which I can recognize this problem at compile time?

**Note:** I used `valgrind --leak-check=full`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: This isn't a memory leak, it's a buffer overrun. Valgrind can find those only when you allocate the buffers with `malloc()`

Comment: Why do you think that the memory corruption is clear? The compiler may not make any assumptions for the semantics of memcpy.

Comment: @swegi: The compiler knows exactly what the semantics of `memcpy` are; that name is reserved for the implementation by the C standard, so even if you write your own `memcpy` function that does something different, the compiler is allowed to disregard it and assume that you are calling the `<string.h>` function.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ gcc -Wall -O1 t.c 
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:642:0,
                 from t.c:3:
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at t.c:13:9:
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:52:3: warning: call to __builtin___memcpy_chk
   will always overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]
```

GCC can recognize *some* of these. That generally requires turning on optimizations (at least `-01`) and warnings (`-Wall`, add `-Wextra` too).

Comment: `-Wall` should be the default :-)

Answer (score 2):

It may not scale to the large program you are really interested in, but you can find this error with [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/):

```
$ frama-c -cpp-command "gcc -C -E -I`frama-c -print-share-path`/libc/ -nostdinc" mem.c `frama-c -print-share-path`/libc/fc_runtime.c -val
...
[value] computing for function memcpy <- main.
    Called from mem.c:13.
.../libc/string.h:54:[value] Function memcpy: precondition got status invalid.
```

This message means that you are calling `memcpy()` with arguments that do not satisfy its contract. In this case the pre-condition that fails is the first in the list, about the validity of the destination for writing:

```
/*@ requires \valid(((char*)dest)+(0..n - 1));                                                                                                                   
  @ requires \valid_read(((char*)src)+(0..n - 1));                                                                                                               
  @ requires \separated(((char *)dest)+(0..n-1),((char *)src)+(0..n-1));                                                                                         
  @ assigns ((char*)dest)[0..n - 1] \from ((char*)src)[0..n-1];                                                                                                  
  @ assigns \result \from dest;                                                                                                                                  
  @ ensures memcmp((char*)dest,(char*)src,n) == 0;                                                                                                               
  @ ensures \result == dest;                                                                                                                                     
  @*/
extern void *memcpy(void *restrict dest,
                    const void *restrict src, size_t n);
```

Comment: This framework looks interesting. If it only would produce useful error messages like `precondition "requires \valid(((char*)dest)+(0..n - 1));" failed`.... :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I will file this suggestion as a feature request. Thanks! (Usability is difficult to get right. When you use something too often you get used to the way it works and can't see these faults anymore)

Comment: To make it usable, I suggest to give each requirement a name like "dest big enough", "src big enough", "no overlap"

Comment: This information is already available within Frama-C's gui (replace frama-c by frama-c-gui). You can navigate to the memcpy function by left-clicking on the name memcpy, and selecting "Go to definition". Then it is immediate which precondition is invalid.